# How to remove media item from both blobs table and items table at the same time from sitecore master db?

Tags: media-library, sql-database

I have added some images in sitecore media library. Those images are getting added in both **dbo.Blobs** and **dbo.Items** tables. I wanted to delete the image data from both the tables.But I don't know how to delete the entries in both the tables at the same time. [image: These are the field in blobs table]

[image]

I want to know, by using which field these tables are related to each other.

Comment: This is just how Sitecore works... a media item is an _item_ and the media itself is added to the blob table, because it needs to be stored somewhere. You should *NOT* be trying to delete this using SQL. Delete it from the Content Tree or use the Sitecore API. I repeat, **you should NOT be trying to delete this using SQL**.

Comment: The problem is, even after deleting the media in content tree i can find the media in blobs table. So If i delete the media in content tree then that item has to be get deleted in the blobs table.Tell me how to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have orphaned blob items in your database, you should use `Clean up databases` tool from Sitecore Control Panel:

[image]

It:

- Removes all invalid language items, i.e., items for which the language does not exist
- Removes field data for non-existing items, including orphan fields
- Removes orphaned items, i.e., items that do not have a parent item
- Removes unused Blob fields of media items
- Rebuilds the descendants tree
- And finally, clears all Sitecore caches

Source: [Improving Sitecore performance – by reducing volume of content](https://thesitecorezone.wordpress.com/2015/11/14/improving-sitecore-performance-by-reducing-volume-of-content/)

Comment: In Sitecore version 8 **Clean up** database is not working fine. In that case how to clean the blob table data?

Answer (score 1):

The Clean Up Databases command doesn't always work when there are a lot of items that need cleaning up. Try this SQL query for cleaning up the Blobs table to remove orphaned rows:

```
DECLARE @UsableBlobs table(
    ID uniqueidentifier
    );

INSERT INTO 
    @UsableBlobs    
select convert(uniqueidentifier,[Value]) as EmpID from [Fields]
where [Value] != '' 
and (FieldId='{40E50ED9-BA07-4702-992E-A912738D32DC}' or FieldId='{DBBE7D99-1388-4357-BB34-AD71EDF18ED3}') 
delete top (10000) from [Blobs] 
where [BlobId] not in (select * from @UsableBlobs)
```